# What should I do about MQ between 979 and 1200?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, responsive-design

So, I'm just getting into responsive design and anything related to it. Mostly I'm studying the Twitter Bootstrap as it is made with LESS and I'm using LESS all the time as CSS framework.

And I've found this media queries widths that they're using :

```
// Landscape phones and down
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }

// Landscape phone to portrait tablet
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

// Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

// Large desktop
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

But I have a question as I'm testing behavior, what happens between `979px` and `1200px` ? Because if I don't add anything, another media query, all my elements loose style upon window resizing or widths between those two values.

Should I add something else or is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: They must not require any special styling for the 980 - 1199 range.  That is the only thing I can really think of.  If you want to style that range there is no harm in defining it.  Take a look at DARL (Device Agnostic Responsive Layout) as well during your responsive learning curve.

Comment: Perhaps :) I'm adding style to the 980 and above too, to be sure :) Because for example my first laptop had 1024px in width, so probably there are a lot of devices there with that width.

Comment: Sounds good. Again I encourage you to read up on Device Agnostic Responsive Layout.  Setting breakpoints for specific devices is a losing battle. With DARL the approach is to set a range that encompasses a device type (phone, tablet, desktop) and let the UI stretch to meet that range.

Comment: Here is the article that got me down the DARL path: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your whole page will scatter and will look weird you must have to configure your css for that

Comment: Indeed, that's what I said it happens, so I added another media query from that point on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm so late but I would to fix that part of the bootstrap's responsive grid too.

If someone is interested, I've added a new LESS file, and some variables.

variables.less (add it at the good place in the grid part)

```
// basic grid
// 980px-1199px
@gridColumnWidth980:      56px; // Feel free to modify this value !
@gridGutterWidth980:      24px; // Feel free to modify this value !
@gridRowWidth980:         (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth980) + (@gridGutterWidth980 * (@gridColumns - 1));

// Fluid grid
// 980px-1199px
@fluidGridColumnWidth980:      percentage(@gridColumnWidth980/@gridRowWidth980);
@fluidGridGutterWidth980:      percentage(@gridGutterWidth980/@gridRowWidth980);
```

new file: responsive-980px-1199px.less

```
// Responsive: Small desktops
// --------------------------------------------------


@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

  // Fixed grid
  #grid > .core(@gridColumnWidth980, @gridGutterWidth980);

  // Fluid grid
  #grid > .fluid(@fluidGridColumnWidth980, @fluidGridGutterWidth980);

  // Input grid
  #grid > .input(@gridColumnWidth980, @gridGutterWidth980);

  // No need to reset .thumbnails here since it's the same @gridGutterWidth

}
```

Then just import the new file to responsive.less file !

```
// Small desktops
@import "responsive-980px-1199px";
```

The grids should not be "wide" between 980px and 1199px anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution: change **@media (min-width: 1200px)** from 1200px to 980px.

This works well as long as the **min-width: 1200px** rules work on a 980px window on your site. It works well for mine. You can have this in a .less file or change the Bootstrap css file as long as you don't mind making the change every time you update Bootstrap. Hopefully they'll fix this gap in a future update.